# App Rejected because of AdSupport

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, admob

My app has just been rejected because of this:

> PLA 3.3.12
>
> We found your app uses the iOS Advertising Identifier but does not
>   include ad functionality. This does not comply with the terms of the
>   iOS Developer Program License Agreement, as required by the App Store
>   Review Guidelines.
>
> Specifically, section 3.3.12 of the iOS Developer Program License
>   Agreement states:
>
> "You and Your Applications (and any third party with whom you have
>   contracted to serve advertising) may use the Advertising Identifier,
>   and any information obtained through the use of the Advertising
>   Identifier, only for the purpose of serving advertising. If a user
>   resets the Advertising Identifier, then You agree not to combine,
>   correlate, link or otherwise associate, either directly or indirectly,
>   the prior Advertising Identifier and any derived information with the
>   reset Advertising Identifier."
>
> Note: iAd does not use the AdSupport framework, ASIdentifierManager,
>   or the Advertising Identifier. Therefore they are not required for iAd
>   implementations and should not be included in your app for iAd
>   support.
>
> Please check your code - including any third-party libraries - to
>   remove any instances of:
>
> class: ASIdentifierManager selector: advertisingIdentifier framework:
>   AdSupport.framework
>
> If you are planning to incorporate ads in a future version, please
>   remove the Advertising Identifier from your app until you have
>   included ad functionality.
>
> To help locate the Advertising Identifier, use the “nm” tool. For
>   information on the “nm” tool, open a terminal window and enter, “man
>   nm.”
>
> If you do not have access to the libraries' source, you may be able to
>   search the compiled binary using the "strings" or "otool" command line
>   tools. The "strings" tool lists the methods that the library calls,
>   and "otool -ov" will list the Objective-C class structures and their
>   defined methods. These techniques can help you narrow down where the
>   problematic code resides.

The thing is that I do have ads (admob) implemented for which adsupport is required.
I read somewhere that Crashlytics is the problem which I also use but never had problems with.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: see http://gmc.yoyogames.com/index.php?showtopic=609058

Comment: wouldn't say duplicate because it is admob and not analytics and yoyogames doesn't really help...